# How to Build for iOS on Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, rhomobile, rhodes

I have built an app on my Windows machine, but obviously cannot use RhoStudio to do a production build for iOS. Is there a simply way of doing this on a Windows PC or do I need a Mac?

I am using Rhodes v4.0.0.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write native apps for iOS you either need a Mac or a virtual machine with Mac (Google Hackintosh).

Another possibility is Phonegap (http://phonegap.com/). As far as i know you don't need a mac with Phonegap.

Comment: You'll need a Mac to sign the app.

Comment: Oh ok, haven't known this.